# How to page results from an endpoint wrapping a Generic Inquiry?

Tags: rest, acumatica

Normally when I want to page results from a REST API endpoint, I would use $top + $skip.

However, when the endpoint wraps a Generic Inquiry, $top + $skip no longer affect the returned results. ($filter still works)

My goal is to export data from [GLTran], so given the high number of records in this table, I need to be able to page the results.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better way to export all columns from [GLTran]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option available to page the GI results via the API. Your best bet is to configure Parameters for a GI the way it shows GLTran for several GL batches (say from Batch X to Batch Y of Module Z). Then you simply PUT parameter values through the API call and export GLTran records in batches.

I also highly recommend you to check the [Exporting Records from Acumatica via REST Contract-Based API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353272/exporting-records-from-acumatica-via-rest-contract-based-api) topic for examples on how to implement pagination on multiple REST requests. The $skip query option does not *skip* the records exported by the API from Acumatica, what in fact it does is excluding the first N records from the resultset returned by the API.