# Exporting Records from Acumatica via REST Contract-Based API

Tags: rest, acumatica, acumatica-kb

This topic will demonstrate how to export records from Acumatica ERP via the REST Contract-Based API. In contrast to the Screen-Based API of Acumatica ERP, the Contract-Based API provides both SOAP and REST interfaces. For more information on the Contract-Based API, see [Acumatica ERP Documentation](https://docref.acumatica.com/wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=91dda8ed-5e92-48a5-a176-9a255506d0d6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Data Export in a Single REST Call

In this example you will explore how to export the following data from Acumatica ERP in a single call via the REST Contract-Based API:

- all stock items existing in the application
- all sales order of the IN type

If you need to export records from Acumatica ERP, use the following URL: 
`http://<Acumatica ERP instance URL>/entity/<Endpoint name>/<Endpoint version>/<Top-level entity>`

`<Top-level entity>` is the name of the entity which you are going to export

### To export all stock items in a single REST call:

To export stock item records from a local `AcumaticaERP` instance by using the ***Default*** endpoint of version ***6.00.001***, you should use the following URL: `http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/6.00.001/StockItem`

Below is the sample code written in C# to export all stock items by sending a single REST call to the ***Default*** endpoint of version ***6.00.001***:

```
using (RestService rs = new RestService(
    @"http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/", "Default/6.00.001",
    username, password, company, branch))
{
    string stockItems = rs.GetList("StockItem");
}
```

### To export all sales order of the IN type in a single REST call:

To export sales orders of the ***IN*** type from a local `AcumaticaERP` instance by using the ***Default*** endpoint of version ***6.00.001***, you should use the following URL: `http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/6.00.001/SalesOrder?$filter=OrderType eq 'IN'`

Below is the sample code written in C# to export all sales orders of the ***IN*** type by sending a single REST call to the ***Default*** endpoint of version ***6.00.001***:

```
using (RestService rs = new RestService(
    @"http://localhost/StackOverflow/", "Default/6.00.001",
    username, password, company, branch))
{
    var parameters = "$filter=OrderType eq 'IN'";
    string inSalesOrders = rs.GetList("SalesOrder", parameters);
}
```

## Pagination with Multiple REST Requests

In this example you will explore how to export the following data from Acumatica ERP in batches via the REST Contract-Based API:

- stock items existing in the application in batches of 10 records
- all sales orders in batches of 100 records

### To export stock items in batches of 10 records with multiple REST calls:

To export first 10 stock items from a local `AcumaticaERP` instance by using the ***Default*** endpoint of version ***6.00.001***, you should use the following URL: `http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/6.00.001/StockItem?$top=10`

Accordingly, to request stock items from 10 to 20, you simply extend the URL above with ***filter*** parameter: `http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/6.00.001/StockItem?$top=10&$filter=InventoryID gt '<InventoryID>'`

`<InventoryID>` is the ID of the last stock item exported with a previous REST call

Below is the sample code written in C# to export all stock items in batches of 10 records by sending multiple REST calls to the ***Default*** endpoint of version ***6.00.001***:

```
using (RestService rs = new RestService(
    @"http://localhost/StackOverflow/", "Default/6.00.001",
    username, password, company, branch))
{
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string parameters = "$top=10";
    string items = rs.GetList("StockItem", parameters);
    var records = json.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(items);

    while (records.Count == 10)
    {
        var inventoryID = records[records.Count - 1]["InventoryID"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        var inventoryIDValue = inventoryID.Values.First();
        string nextParameters = parameters + "&" + 
            "$filter=" + string.Format("InventoryID gt '{0}'", inventoryIDValue);
        items = rs.GetList("StockItem", nextParameters);
        records = json.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(items);
    }
}
```

### To export all sales orders in batches of 100 records with multiple REST calls: ##

To export first 100 sales orders from a local `AcumaticaERP` instance by using the ***Default*** endpoint of version ***6.00.001***, you should use the following URL: `http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/6.00.001/SalesOrder?$top=100`

Since the primary key of the **Sales Order** entity is composed by the ***Order Type*** and the ***Order Number***, in this example you will be using a combination of **filter** parameters for the ***Order Type*** and ***Order Number*** fields:

- to request sales orders from 100 to 200 of the ***SO*** type, you should use the following URL: `http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/6.00.001/SalesOrder?$top=100&$filter=OrderType eq 'SO' and OrderNbr gt '<OrderNbr>'`

`<OrderNbr>` is the number of the last sales order exported with a previous REST call

- accordingly, to request first 100 sales orders of the next to ***SO*** type, you should use the following URL: `http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/6.00.001/SalesOrder?$top=100&$filter=OrderType gt 'SO' and OrderNbr gt ''`

Below is the sample code written in C# to export all sales orders in batches of 100 records with multiple REST calls to the ***Default*** endpoint of version ***6.00.001***:

```
using (RestService rs = new RestService(
    @"http://localhost/StackOverflow/", "Default/6.00.001",
    username, password, company, branch))
{
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string parameters = "$top=100";
    string items = rs.GetList("SalesOrder", parameters);
    var records = json.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(items);

    bool sameOrderType = true;
    while (records.Count > 0 && (records.Count == 100 || !sameOrderType))
    {
        var orderType = records[records.Count - 1]["OrderType"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        var orderTypeValue = orderType.Values.First();
        var orderNbr = records[records.Count - 1]["OrderNbr"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        var orderNbrValue = orderNbr.Values.First();

        string nextParameters = parameters + "&" + "$filter=" +
            string.Format("OrderType {0} '{1}'", sameOrderType ? "eq" : "gt", orderTypeValue) + " and " +
            string.Format("OrderNbr gt '{0}'", sameOrderType ? orderNbrValue : "''" );
        items = rs.GetList("SalesOrder", nextParameters);
        records = json.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(items);
        sameOrderType = records.Count == 100;
    }
}
```

To communicate with the REST Contract-Based API of Acumatica ERP your client application must always perform the following 3 steps:

1. log into Acumatica ERP instance and get cookie with user session information
2. interact with one of Contract-Based API endpoints available on Acumatica ERP instance
3. log out from Acumatica ERP to close user session

All samples provided in this topic were built with the **Default** endpoint, always deployed as part of the standard Acumatica ERP installation process. On the **Web Service Endpoints** screen (SM.20.70.60) you can view the details of existing endpoints or configure your custom endpoints of the Acumatica ERP contract-based web services:
[image]

For your reference, below is implementation of the **RestService** class used in all samples above to interact with the Contract-Based web service of Acumatica ERP:

```
public class RestService : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _acumaticaBaseUrl;
    private readonly string _acumaticaEndpointUrl;

    public RestService(string acumaticaBaseUrl, string endpoint,
        string userName, string password,
        string company, string branch)
    {
        _acumaticaBaseUrl = acumaticaBaseUrl;
        _acumaticaEndpointUrl = _acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/" + endpoint + "/";
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(
            new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseCookies = true,
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
            })
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(_acumaticaEndpointUrl),
            DefaultRequestHeaders =
            {
                Accept = {MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/json")}
            }
        };

        var str = new StringContent(
            new JavaScriptSerializer()
                .Serialize(
                    new
                    {
                        name = userName,
                        password = password,
                        company = company,
                        branch = branch
                    }),
                    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        _httpClient.PostAsync(acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/auth/login", str)
            .Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        _httpClient.PostAsync(_acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/auth/logout",
            new ByteArrayContent(new byte[0])).Wait();
        _httpClient.Dispose();
    }

    public string GetList(string entityName)
    {
        var res = _httpClient.GetAsync(_acumaticaEndpointUrl + entityName)
            .Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    public string GetList(string entityName, string parameters)
    {
        var res = _httpClient.GetAsync(_acumaticaEndpointUrl + entityName + "?" + parameters)
            .Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish i had of found this 6 months ago!

Comment: Hi, is there an endpoint for me to call once logged in to get this Default Endpoint string for the installed version of Acumatica? ("6.00.001" in your example) Looking at an example console app on their github, it is simply hardcoded???